# No encuentro solución ERROR in ./src/global.scss?

Tags: nodejs, npm, ionic4

Estoy tratando de compilar un proyecto pero me encuentro con el sig. error:

````
```ERROR in ./src/global.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/global.scss)```
````

he intentado con un par de repuestas pero sin éxito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre encontrar la solución a mi problema el error fue en el windows build tools el ssl esta en true y no permite, según parece :D.

**Primero** cambie de versión del node a 11.1.0 con el versionador de nvm,
**Segundo** corri `npm install --global windows-build-tools`
**Tercero** elimine el node modules 
**Cuarto** `npm install --global windows-build-tools`
**Quinto** `npm c set strict-ssl false` seteo el ssl de windows- build tools
como falso.
**Sexto** `npm c get strict-ssl -g` esto le hago para confirmar que esta en
false el open ssl